# php - let the visitor download a remote file, chunk by chunk (range)

Tags: php, file, stream, readfile, fsockopen

It's a recurring question on StackOverflow and i've browsed to all existing suggestions unsuccessfully.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
- visitor comes to my webpage and i have to send him a very LARGE file for download.
- that file is located on a REMOTE server, and requires either Basic Auth or Cookie. Only me owns the cookie/credentials.
- I successfully managed to download that file using wget then serve it to the visitor via the X-sendfile mod (Apache), but it requires waiting for the end user before download.
- I'd like to serve the download asap, which mean my website would act like some kind of proxy or something.
- I tried using bunch of codes with cURL, fsockopen/feof, etc but either it almost crashes Apache once in a while, either it's a blocking connexion (visitor cannot browse the website anymore as long as he has not finished downloading), either it's destroying my ressources since php tries to put that huge file in memory i guess.

So to sum up:
- I should be able to serve the remote file for downloading as soon as possible
- Ideally serving it chunk by chunk / range by range ?

extra info: PHP 5.2.13, Gentoo, libcurl 5.2.13

Comment: I'm surprised such an unusual requirement is a recurring question. Normally you would just use the remote server or a script on the remote server to serve such a file instead of tripling the bandwidth usage of this very LARGE file by sending the same file from one server to another, just to send it out from that second one. It seems like a reconsideration of your architecture would be a more sensible solution

Comment: I want to hide the remote servers + I have unlimited bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Sending it chunk by chunk would require some kind of torrent solution from what I can tell.

Comment: It's nothing like that, Torrents use chunks that's true.
But So do a lot of other programs and protocols.
Also Torrents are peer to peer file transfer, which has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the same problem, and yet I could not resolve it.

But there is something that I'm pretty sure you can use. I don't because I consider it dirty coding, but since you are in a hurry, or were 10 months ago(!), I can suggest you [this](http://www.glype.com/):

Glype proxy script, is a powerful php based proxy.

- Install it
- Go to **admin.php?settings**
- Enable **Hotlink**
- Probably have to **disable Gzip compression**
- Disable **SSL warning**
- Disable **caching**
- Check ***Resume transfers*** (important)

These are all I can think of, try this and then send
`$_POST['u']` to `includes/process.php?action=update`

It should work. If I ever test it, I'll let you know about the result...

Hope It Helps.